# Row number in ViewCell

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When creating a custom ViewCell inside a ListView, is there any way to access its row number?  Sure, I can put it inside the data item that becomes the binding context, but that's a hassle.  In Android, when an adaptor creates a view, the row number is passed to it!

Comment: You mean access the row while the rows are being "inserted" in the ListView?

Comment: Yes.  The view tree for a row is created by the template, possibly by a functor that I define.  The binding context is the underlying object for the row, and I can use binding to setup visual elements in that view tree.  However, the row number is unavailable, unless it is explicitly present in the object.